# Cloud Storage Text to BigQuery using GCP Template

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow

I'm trying to execute a pipeline using the GCP template available at:
https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/templates/provided-templates#cloud-storage-text-to-bigquery

But I'm getting the error:

```
2018-03-30 (15:35:17) java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to match any files with the pattern: gs://.......
```

Can anyone share a working CSV file to be used as an input for running that pipeline?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem was between chair and keyboard, you just need to create a CSV file accordingly to the data structure defined in the JSON file and transformed by the JS file.

Comment: Feel free to accept your answer so that the community sees that the question is now solved. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I see that this has been answered but I was having a similar issue and this answer was partial for me - as it turns out, the path pattern (at the moment, at least) in the template does not support some types of patterns.
For example, for multiple CSV files across multiple sub-directories in a given GCS path (this was my use-case):

> gs://bucket-name/dir/

The pattern that will work is:

> gs://bucket-name/dir/*/*.csv

These patterns, although they are valid via gsutil ls and return the correct files, will not work in the template:

> gs://bucket-name/dir/*
>
> gs://bucket-name/dir/*.csv